# Is this example concerning Einstein's summation wrong?

Tags: summation, tensors

I'm going through a book on tensors and I found the following example:

[image]

But this does not seem right to me because the Einstein's summation convention states: sum whenever there are two repeated indices one as superscript and the other as subscript.

The summation range must be from $1$ to $n$.

In the expression $$a_{ij} x^i x^j$$ we have a pair of repeated indices $i$ and $j$, each ocurring once as superscript and another as subscript. In my understanding of the rulle it should be

$$\begin{align*}
a_{ij} x^i x^j&=a_{1j} x^1 x^j+\ldots +a_{nj} x^n x^j\\
&=(a_{11} (x^1)^2+a_{12} x^1 x^2+\ldots +a_{1n} x^1 x^n)+\ldots +(a_{n1} x^n x^1 +\ldots +a_{nn} (x^n)^2).
\end{align*}
$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: What book is this from? Was there anything special about $a$ in the preceding text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: (i) should contain $n^2$ terms, whereas the solution given only brings the $n$ "diagonal" ones to mind. The only way this can be OK is if the matrix $a$ is diagonal.